# Grails template rendering and the DOM

Tags: grails

In grails if you rerender a template back on top of itself to update information on a GSP does the old template's DOM get updated or does the new template cause DOM issues by having its own DOM? And also, is it considered good practice to rerender a template on top of itself to update information? I just used this approach for the first time and hence I was wondering if it is considered good practice.

Comment: Perhaps some code from your GSP or controller might help people understand the approach you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a partial page updates using AJAX is very common with many modern web based UIs or websites. This has little to do with Grails and it's easier to think about what's going on if you think of what is being sent back to the browser as just HTML and ignore the fact it's coming from a Grails template.

That said, your question of "... does the old template's DOM get updated or does the new template cause DOM issues by having its own DOM?" is slightly awkward because templates or HTML fragments don't have a DOM but the entire page as whole within the browser does.

What is happening is the page is rendering, being loaded by the browser and parsed into a DOM, then displayed. When you do a partial page update the browser parses the new fragment into DOM elements and replaces/updates portions of the existing DOM with the new elements.

All in all, this is considered a good practice since it allows you the developer to only update what information needs to be changed within the DOM and not refresh the entire DOM by reloading the entire page.

I hope this helps, if not please comment and I will explain further with theoretical examples if needed.

Comment: Thanks that was extremely helpful. It really helped to think of what is being sent to the browser regardless of the underlying framework might be (e.g. Grails in my case).

Comment: You're more than welcome. Glad it helped put things into perspective.